# jquery dynamic tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip

Want to show tooltip with dynamic data on clicking to 
Have tried many plugins, but didnt achieved my goal.

Here my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tbl td").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCellData")',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                time: $(this).parent().children().index($(this)),
                name: $('td:first', $(this).parents('tr')).text(),
                type: $('input[name="t"]:checked').val()
            },
            success: function (response) {    
                   ///
                   ///        HERE I NEED TO SHOW TOOLTIP
                   /// 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I need to use 'response' in callback, to show it in tooltip, on muse click to cell.
Can you please reccomend me plugin, for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tbl td").click(function () {
            var $td = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCellData")',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    time: $(this).parent().children().index($(this)),
                    name: $('td:first', $(this).parents('tr')).text(),
                    type: $('input[name="t"]:checked').val()
                },
                success: function (response) {
                   var pos = $td.position();
                   $('#tooltip').remove();
                   $('<div/>',{html:response, id:'tooltip'}).css({left:pos.left+10+'px', top:pos.top+10+'px'}).prependTo( 'body' );
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

and in your css create these rules

```
#tooltip{
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    padding:15px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000;
}
```

You can style the tooltip anyway you  like of-course..

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/fFDhB/1/

Comment: Is it possible to make such mobile friendly tooltip ?

Answer (score 0):

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/

or please mention the ones that have you tryed

Answer (score 0):

I really like this one:
http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/

K